# Betrayal at house on the Hill: Widow's Walk - Blueprint item

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill, betrayal-widows-walk

The Blueprint item from the expansion Widow's Walk states that you can move between rooms with dumbwaiters. Does this mean you can move between any room with a dumbwaiter even on a different floor? If so that makes several haunts unplayable if the Traitor has it.

Comment: Can you explain which haunts you think are unplayable, and why this would make them unplayable?

Comment: Some of the haunts require Traitor to get places and do things, others buff the Traitor until the heroes do X. In both circumstances being able to move from the basement to the roof for example for one space of movement may not make it unplayable, but incredibly one sided. May have been on a little bit of tilt when I said unplayable :P

Comment: In the base game there are situations that can make the game almost unplayable for one side or the other. The traitor being affected by the music box coupled with continuously bad rolls (in a scenario where they have no monsters to control), the haunt starting on only the second or third Omen when not much of the house has been explored (for haunts that involve hunting, specific rooms being found, or involve the rooms being systematically blocked), or the traitor trying to hunt someone through a circular house structure, are some of the more likely scenarios that can cause this.

Comment: That's fair I suppose, but I guess my question is still there, is that how it works? That much free movement is still op in my opinion for either side most of the time

Comment: Rule 1 of being a hero in Betrayal has always been "Don't let the Traitor reach the Mystic Elevator".  The blueprints are harder for th e Traitor to aquire than th e Elevator, so I don't think that they unbalance the game any more that it already is.

Answer (score 4):

You might be missing the dumbwaiter icons in general allow anyone to move to different floors; that is their primary purpose.

> Some room tiles include an elevator-like symbol on them, in addition to any Item, Event, or Omen symbol they might have. This symbol signifies that the room has access to a dumbwaiter, which players may use to move to a Landing one floor up or down. It costs 1 space of movement to use a dumbwaiter, plus 1 space to move onto the Landing.

So while it costs an extra movement, you do not need the blueprint item to make use of the dumbwaiters.

What the blueprint allows is to move from one dumbwaiter icon to another as a movement, as opposed to the normal use which requires you to move to the landing of a floor 1 below or 1 above where you are. So yes, the blueprint makes the dumbwaiters better, but it does not give them the ability to move to a different floor; that already was part of the dumbwaiter rules.

Comment: Ok I think that may have answered it somewhat, my question I suppose was can you use a dumb waiter room in the basement to a dumb waiter room on the roof with 1 space of movement with the blueprint?

Comment: @MarkShadix Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the lack of restriction on traveling to other floors is intentional. After all, that's the whole point of dumbwaiters. They are miniature elevators meant for food or other goods.

[image: Traditional dumbwaiter]

[image: Modern commercial-grade dumbwaiter]

Comment: I don't think the real-life use of dumbwaiters is necessarily relevant to the game rules. Especially if you need a special item to use a dumbwaiter to travel from one floor to another.

Comment: @Gendolkari, You are gravely mistaken. The definition of words is quite relevant. Of course you are bound by the rules -- for example, I couldn't claim that a dumbwaiter couldn't be used to travel to another room on the same floor even though that makes no sense knowing what a dumbwaiter is -- but there's no point in repeating the rule the OP already stated. The OP is asking if the lack if restriction to travel to other floors is intentional, so one *has* to go outside the rules to answer their question.